# paypal payments advanced (PPA) - Testing Intigration - Error coming

Tags: paypal-sandbox

We just set up paypal account wiht PPA enabled. We setup the php code so that I am getting access token. I have done all corrected as mentioned
[here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/quick-start-guides/paypal-payments-advanced-hosted-pages).

We are getting the payflow form in iframe correctly. Once we enter the details `4111111111111111` and `12 12` we are getting the following error from paypal. Test mode is on and we have added a correct sandbox account.

Some required information is missing or incorrect. Please correct the fields below and try again.

```
Error: Information entered incorrect. Try again.
```

Can anyone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It was the issue coming due to wrong API credential passing. Just trimmed the values and it was sending response back.

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue coming due to wrong API credential passing. Just trimmed the values and it was sending response back.